# java.lang.NullPointerException at run

Tags: java, android

I don't figure out why it return to me this errors, please help me!! :(
This are errors:

```
10-31 15:33:28.595: E/Trace(7356): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appuniradiocesena/com.example.appuniradiocesena.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at com.example.appuniradiocesena.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java:77)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
10-31 15:33:29.125: E/AndroidRuntime(7356):     ... 11 more
```

and this is my first class when it run:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.ScrapeException;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Scraper;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.Stream;
import net.moraleboost.streamscraper.scraper.IceCastScraper;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SwipeyTabsSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private Button streamButton;

private ImageButton playButton;

private TextView textStreamed;
private TextView textSong;

private boolean isPlaying;

private StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

private SwipeyTabs mTabs;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private static final String [] TITLES = {
    "Live Stream",
    "Palinsesto",
    "Programmi",
    "Eventi",
};




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipeytab);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabs = (SwipeyTabs) findViewById(R.id.swipey_tab);

    SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter adapter = new SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(this,
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabs.setAdapter(adapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
/*
    Inizializza();

    //new AsyncTaskProc().execute();

    //new Timer().schedule(new IceCastPoll(), 1000);
     */
}

private void startStreamingAudio() {
    try { 
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        if ( audioStreamer != null) {
            audioStreamer.interrupt();
        }


        audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this, textStreamed, playButton, streamButton,progressBar);
        audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://r35798.ovh.net:8000/listen",1677, 214);
        streamButton.setEnabled(false);
    } catch (IOException e) {               
    }

}
private void Inizializza()
{
    textStreamed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_kb_streamed);
    streamButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stream);
    streamButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startStreamingAudio();
        }});


    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    playButton.setEnabled(false);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().isPlaying()) {
                audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            } else {
                audioStreamer.getMediaPlayer().start();

                audioStreamer.startPlayProgressUpdater();
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            }
            isPlaying = !isPlaying;
        }});
}
private class SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
SwipeyTabsAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;

    public SwipeyTabsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SwipeyTabFragment.newInstance(TITLES[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    public TextView getTab(final int position, SwipeyTabs root) {
        TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);
        view.setText(TITLES[position]);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}


public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Uscita").setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Uscita Programma", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);

                    return true;
                }
            });
    ;


    return true;
}

public class IceCastPoll extends TimerTask {

    public IceCastPoll() {

    }

    @TargetApi(9)
    public void run() {
        Scraper scraper = new IceCastScraper();
        try {

            List<Stream> streams=null;
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("http://r35798.ovh.net:8000"));            
            for (Stream stream: streams) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),stream.getCurrentSong(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));
            }
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ScrapeException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}


class AsyncTaskProc extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    List<Stream> streams=null;

    protected void onPostExecute()
    {

        textSong =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentSong);

        try {
            for (Stream stream: streams) {

                textSong.setText((stream.getCurrentSong()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
    @TargetApi(9)
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {



        Scraper scraper = new IceCastScraper();

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try {
            streams = scraper.scrape(new URI("http://r35798.ovh.net:8000/"));
        } catch (ScrapeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        return (null);
    }


}
}
```

when I try to compile and run the application crash, and I can't understand why.
Thanks;

Comment: And which one is line 77 of SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java?

Comment: Either the ViewPager or swipey_tab are not in your layout so it couldn't find them.

Comment: com.example.appuniradiocesena.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java:77) check the code or double click this line in debugger some component is having null value and your using it according to my view it should be that two view which you have mentioned is not present in your xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the important part of the stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.appuniradiocesena.SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.onCreate(SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java:77)
```

--> You should find the cause of the `NullPointerException` by looking at line 77 of `SwipeyTabsSampleActivity.java`.

Maybe you are calling `findViewById()` on IDs that do not exist in your layout ? (which would make this method return `null`)

Comment: Thanks all, the name is swipeytasb not swipey_tab....so findById is Null:)so I noob